# Wordpress admin textarea not respecting line break or html

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, elementor

When working with frontend post submissions manager (plugin) in wordpress, i wanted this textarea to have working line breaks. Yes, i guess i should have used the full editor instead, but now i have ACF enabled for 100+ posts, so i don't think i can change it now without screwing things upp =)

Please help me! I want this field too somehow enable html or at least line breaks.

```
<div class="fpsm-field-wrap">
                    <label>testlable</label>
                    <div class="fpsm-field fpsm-custom-textarea">
                        <input type="hidden" name="fpsm_included_custom_fields[]" value="testvalue">
                                                        <textarea name="fpsm_custom_fields[local-area]">This is not working when i write line breaks and other html things like <br> <p> etc etc </textarea>
                                                    </div>
                </div>
```

I tried linebreaks, and some basic html. But since the textarea is rich text, it just deletes it when saved.